# Always redownload a file when opening it in NetBeans IDE 6.8

Tags: download, file-transfer, netbeans

I'm using NetBeans IDE 6.8.

When I open a file, NetBeans opens an old file from my computer, not the actual one from the web-server. The problem is when some one else has edited the file on the web-server I need to download the file before I open it, so I don't lose the new changes.

What I want to do is that NetBeans always download the file from the web-server when I open a file. Do you know how I can make NetBeans to do this automatically?

Comment: What do you mean when you say download file from server ? Are you using version control, a share drive, or from a web server ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm using version control. If I right-click a file I have the option to see the "Local History", is that "version control"? By downloading I mean downloading the files from the web-server.

Comment: ok then, at least you should tell your OS, and the software that you use to check the "local history"

Comment: OS: Vista. "local history" is from inside NetBeans IDE 6.8.

Comment: Well I have just created a fresh netbeans project, right-click on a newly created file and still have the option "local history".  
It seems to me you don't have any kind of version control (I mean you can't possibly have if you didn't set it up), in which case what you want can't be done.

Comment: now if you tell us how the environment is set up (i.e how you download the file, who can edit the file, how you save the file when you are done, who manage the server) maybe we can help you more

Comment: I just created a project, added a folder on the web-server as the root-folder of the project, then all the files were downloaded. I save the file by using ctrl+s (and then the file also gets uploaded to the web-server).  I can control the servers files using a ftp-program. Other people can change files on the web-server using ftp-programs. Do you need any more information, just tell me.

Comment: Bounty removed as OP has changed to a different application. Also please update the question rather then posting an answer. Will close as no longer relevant once updated.

Comment: In case anyone doesn't get the problem: Netbeans remote projects become completely dangerous when other users accessing the server are involved because there's no check for out-of-sync files. Eclipse's Remote System Explorer does the right thing here: check for modification before overwrite and prompt the user for what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have switched to [Aptana](http://www.aptana.org) now.

Works as I want.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that you are using version control,
if the file is in a netbeans project then you can set up the project to use the version control then netbeans will know about the "server" that you want it to download from
If it's not under source control then, how can netbeans possibly know about the file's server counterpart? Perhaps you can use [dropbox](http://dropbox.com) then?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Ant (http://ant.apache.org/) or maven(http://maven.apache.org/). For maven You mast create new maven project, for Ant you can edit build.xml because Ant is used by default to build projects.